# Why Google analytics show zero result in search console section in acquisition?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, keywords, landing-page

Google analytics show zero result in search console section in acquisition, While i applied no segment on my result and also long tie a go I connected both GA and Search console by each other. 
You can see screen-shut of query result here:

[image]

and also here is my landing-page result:

[image]

In other hand my search console show huge amount of data about our search queries and landing pages, 
Some thing is wrong here, 
can anyone help me?
thanks

Comment: Make sure you have Analytics connected to the right Search Console site

Comment: @TonyMcCreath How can I realize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What values are showing in Search Console?

If none, confirm you have the correct version of the site verified and the correct version associated with the Google Analytics property.

This means if your site is https://www.example.com, you must verify and connect https://www.example.com

Google sees sites running http, or without www as different sites.

Comment: You are right, I connect it again to the right property, But still showing zero, does it takes time to show data?

Comment: In Admin->Property->All Product you should see a Search Console entry. Click on it an check if it is connected to the correct site. i.e. the one that gets traffic. http or https, with or without www. They are all different sites and only one will probably see any traffic.

Comment: There's a 2 day delay for data in search console, so it should be the same in analytics